# QT / mingw - struct within struct

Tags: qt

I have the following c program that compiles under Visual Studio but fails in QT 5.2.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct structA
{
    int x;
    struct structB
    {
        int d;
    } y;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct structA ad;
    struct structB ab;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get in QT is

```
error: aggregate 'structB ab' has incomplete type and cannot be definedstruct structB ab;
```

Any ideas why this works in Visual Studio and not QT?

Comment: is that `c` compiler or `c++` compiler?

Answer (score 1):

When I pasted your code into a file and compile it on Mac using GCC (which is more or less the same toolchain as MinGW) I get that error you report.  I can make the error go away by changing the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct structA
{
    int x;
    struct structB
    {
        int d;
    } y;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct structA ad;
    // Tell the compiler where to find structB
    struct structA::structB ab;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is correct, by which I mean the structB type is not properly declared, and it does need the scoping to make it visible.

I'm not sure how it was able to compile under Visual Studio.  I tried pasting the same code into a file on Windows and compiling it with MSVC 2012, and I got this error:

```
C:\Users\sarah_000\depot\structs\main.cpp:15: error: C2079: 'ab' uses undefined struct 'main::structB'
```

On Windows I had to make the same change to get it to compile.  Are you sure the code is identical in both cases?  There is not perhaps a 'using' or other scoping operator that Visual Studio helpfully added?